# Loading a list from database on selection of value from another list

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, hibernate, drop-down-menu

I have 2 drop down lists in my web page.A Country List and Province List.
When page loads, my country list is populated from data base and then on selection of a country from the list, the province list of that country should be populated also from the database.

(I am using hibernate reverse engineering for creating database connection files and bean classes e.t.c)

What i am doing is after populating the country list, i get the value of the country selected using jquery script then pass it via a url using ajax to the controller class. Which i will attach below.

The problem i face is when i select a country from the country list, instead of populating the province list the two dropdown boxes are printed again and the province list box remains empty.

Here is my jsp file

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Selection Page</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form name="locationSelection" method="POST">

    Select Country:
        <br>
        <select name="countryList" id="countryList">
            <option value="">Select Country</option>
            <c:if test="${!empty countryList}">
                <c:forEach items="${countryList}" var="cont">
                    <option   value=${cont.countryId}>${cont.countryName}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
        </select>
        <br><br>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            $("#countryList").change(function() 
            {
                var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();
                $.ajax
                ({
                    url : "a.html?cID="+selectedValue+'',
                    success : function(result) 
                    {
                        $("#prvContatiner").html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>

        Select Province:
        <div id="prvContatiner">
            <select name="provinceList" id="provinceList">
                <option value="">Select Province</option>
                      <c:if test="${!empty provinceList}">
                <c:forEach items="${provinceList}" var="cont">
                    <option   value=${cont.provinceId}>${cont.provinceDesc}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
        </select> 
            </select>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

and here is my controller java class

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import dao.TblCountryDAO;
import dao.TblProvinceDAO;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SelectionController extends HttpServlet {
    void ProcessorRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String operation = request.getParameter("op");
        System.out.println("Operation: "+operation);
        String cID = request.getParameter("cId");
        if (cID == null) 
        {
            System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
            TblCountryDAO dao = new TblCountryDAO();
            List<?> countryList = dao.findAll();
            request.setAttribute("countryList", countryList);
            RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp");
            reqDispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("in elseif");

            TblProvinceDAO dao = new TblProvinceDAO();
            List<?> provinceList = dao.findByProperty("tblCountry.countryId", Integer.parseInt(cID));
            request.setAttribute("provinceList", provinceList);
            RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp");
            reqDispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        ProcessorRequest(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        ProcessorRequest(req, resp);
    }
}
```

I am attaching the web.xml file just in case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name></display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.SelectionController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/a.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Any other suggestion for doing the task will also be greatly appreciated

Comment: if you are using chrome press `F12` and click on `Network` tab and then select dropdown which will trigger request and you can see it's response!

Comment: i have checked it. the list of country appears in the place of options in the country correctly.every thing else is same with no change in the province block

Comment: actually its not going in the else block in the controller class. i already checked the province list by printing the result and the list is returned fine. but the problem is how to make it come in the else block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for wrong parameter `request.getParameter("cId");` should be `request.getParameter("cID");` using `cId` will return you `null` value and you will get main.jsp in response

Comment: try rebuild and deploy code probably your change has not been reflected

Comment: oh great. one problem solved but the extra country box and province box still keeps appearing

Comment: user console.log(result) for debugging your response, check this https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: will do. thanks alot for your help. i hope the second issue gets resolved too.. Its like the whole form is published again in place of the province list box.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can switch to an another way to accomplish the same task with the help of json

in the controller you are getting the list of province. Use any of Json library such as google gson or json.org and convert it into json array of object like this

```
[{
"id":1,
"name":"Delhi"
},{
...
...
},
...
]
```

and directly print the json array using PrintWriter.

and then in your ajax success response generate the options like this -

```
$.ajax
                ({
                    url : "a.html?cID="+selectedValue+'',
                    success : function(result) 
                    {
                        $("#provinceList").html('');
                        for(var i=0;i<result.size;i++){
                            var option = '<option value="'+result[i].id+'">'+result[i].name+'</option>'
                            $("#provinceList").append(option);
                        }
                    }
                });
```